# Delegate Call fails

Tags: solidity, delegatecall

I have the following function

```
   enum OptionType {Invalid, Put, Call}

   function create(
    uint256 period,
    uint256 amount,
    uint256 strike,
    OptionType optionType
) {
    ....
}
```

When I try to delegatecall this function from another contract using this

```
address(contractAddress).delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSelector("create(uint256,uint256,uint256,uint8)",1,1,1,1));
```

I get the error

**function selector was not recognized and there's no fallback function**

Comment: can you try ```bytes4(keccak256("create(uint256,uint256,uint256,uint8)")), 1,1,1,1```

Comment: @hack3r_0m That fails and even this one fails


                abi.encodeWithSignature(
                    "create(uint256,uint256,uint256,uint8)",
                    1,
                    1,
                    1,
                    1
                )